# Base what? Oh, great, now I need magic

Tags: riddle, cipher, computer-puzzle

> This cipher's too hard to solve by itself.
>
> This short riddle provides sufficient help.
>
> You must consult the fifth man;
>
> He'll lend a hand,
>
> And less information quite appropriate.

```
?/9f4iG0)z4jJ.Am&A+>9s.C2DXA:CDtAAc:AAE"j"&"C"8MBtIOFhUE@AuWuWs7[QOR7IGH7fuE|QbLQtzN?[/(_4_U^f@f{I37WQ]a!2GGd*YKth/.[5.w]V4@9W@kZ38[:M~O=t("iM@C
```

Good luck!

Comment: Well, this looks interesting. Welcome to Puzzling.SE and good luck!

Comment: Hint: the fifth man is not very hospitable towards Windows users...

Comment: Something linefeed character related?

Comment: @ToddSewell No, something that Linux has had since forever but you'd be hard-pressed to access on Windows.

Comment: i.e. the fifth man... how else could you write that...?

Comment: man(5) (the fifth man section on linux & others) is, apparently, on file formats and conventions. I couldn't remember anything in the fifth section off the top of my head, but things like 'gitignore' and 'crontab' are in it, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I got to this solution but I highly doubt this one is correct.

> Solution "PuTTY"
>  I used the linux base64 decoding to get this one.
>  I tried to fiddle around with the less command but couldn't figure out if this is the right path to go down.
>  Any more hints?
> Edit:
>  It looks like it has something todo with the magic and file command in Linux which belong to Section 5 of the man pages. But either my Linux is too old, RHEL isn't supposed to be used or i didnt find the right approach using the file command. I'm always running into Syntax or unexpected Token errors.

Comment: Hint: base what? I thought base64 and base32 were the only ones! (It's not one of those)

Comment: Also, I think you'll need to consult man #5 soon afterwards.

Comment: Edited my answer